# Azure App Service: Unable to download APK file

Tags: azure, service, download, apk

I'm trying to download an APK file(Android Package file) from my Azure website. I have a very simple virtual application with the file and index.html page that offers a download link. Here is the index.html file contents:

```html
<a href="com.curiasystems.jcms.droid.parking.apk" download> Download Link </a>
```

The APK has been uploaded to the site via FTP.

When the site renders and the link appears, the file fails to download. Here is the error Chrome gives me:

> This error means that you're trying to download a file that doesn't
>   exist on this site or has been moved to another area of the site.
>
> To fix the error, contact the website owner, or try to find the file
>   on a different site.

Here is what I did to test this. I renamed the file to "zip" and updated the down load link and the file downloaded as a ZIP file. I have added a mimeMap setting to the web.config here is the entry:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
          <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="WordPress: https://www.mywebsite.com/staging" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
          </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
    </configuration>
```

I have also have restarted the App Service to make sure the web.config took affect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Hapster

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone, I found the issue, I was adding the mime type to the WRONG web.config file. Once I corrected this it worked fine.